# sql(ite) - grouping data on same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some data in a table called UniqueCrash, which has a hash value, and an issue_id (it's an external bug tracker ID).

What I want to find is a list of UniqueCrash rows where the same hash value - since it is a hash of the call stack - has been assigned to more than one bug tracker ID (because it means that a duplicate bug has been logged).

My test data looks like this (ID, hash, Issue ID):

---

```
1 | 12345 | Bug 1
2 | 12345 | Bug 2
3 | 12345 | Bug 3
4 | 123456 | Bug 4
```

And I want my result to look like this:

---

```
1 | 12345 | Bug 1
2 | 12345 | Bug 2
3 | 12345 | Bug 3
```

(i.e. to just remove the last entry - that hash is only used once)

I don't really know what this technique is called, if indeed there is a name for it. So far I have a query that seems to give almost the right data back:

```
SELECT UniqueCrash.id, hash, issue_id 
FROM UniqueCrash
WHERE hash IN 
    ( SELECT hash FROM 
    ( SELECT UniqueCrash.id, hash, issue_id 
        FROM UniqueCrash WHERE
            UniqueCrash.issue_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY hash, issue_id ) 
    GROUP BY hash HAVING COUNT(issue_id) > 1 )
ORDER BY hash ASC, id ASC
```

But whilst it gives the 3 correct (by ID) rows back, it looks like the issue ID for row 1 vs. row 2 are round the wrong way and I can't see why.

Can anyone suggest a better way to rewrite this query (and one that actually works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `COUNT DISTINCT` to do that :

```
SELECT `id`, `hash`, `issue_id` 
FROM UniqueCrash 
WHERE `hash` IN (
             SELECT `hash` from UniqueCrash
             GROUP BY `hash`
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `issue_id`) > 1)
ORDER BY `hash` ASC, `id`  ASC
```

See [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce852/1)